# Doubts about deployment of wpad

Tags: google-chrome, apache-http-server, proxy, dhcp-server, wpad

I mounted a server (in ubuntu) and I'm going to deploy wpad for autoconfiguration of the proxy on the computers. I have performed the following procedure:

I have created 3 files, because I read somewhere that IE only works with .dat (modern versions) and .da (old versions) and Chrome (etc) with .pac:

```
proxy.pac wpad.da wpad.dat
```

With the same content...

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {

// If the requested website is hosted within the internal network, send direct.
if (isPlainHostName(host) ||
    shExpMatch(host, "*.local") ||
    isInNet(dnsResolve(host), "192.168.0.0",  "255.255.0.0") ||
    isInNet(dnsResolve(host), "127.0.0.0", "255.255.255.0"))
    return "DIRECT";

return "PROXY 192.168.0.1:3128";

}
```

To publish them in apache and divulge them with [option 252 of dhcp](https://findproxyforurl.com/deploying-wpad/), so all my computers go to my squid proxy

**I have two questions:**

1. Do I really need the 3 files?
2. Is the content of the files correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should be able to get away with one `.dat` file. Both chrome and firefox can work with it. For chrome there is a built in handy tool which tells you which pac file is used just use this url [chrome://net-internals/#proxy](http://chrome://net-internals/#proxy)
2. Syntax wise I think you should be alright. Functionality wise it really depends on your needs.
   `isPlainHostName(host)` if the host in the request is 'plain' i.e.contains no full stops
   `shExpMatch(host, "*.local")` if the request url ends with '.local'
   `isInNet(dnsResolve(host), "192.168.0.0",  "255.255.0.0")` if request host resolves to an ip is in the range 192.168.0.0-192.168.255.255
   `isInNet(dnsResolve(host), "127.0.0.0", "255.255.255.0")` same as above just the range is 127.0.0.0-127.0.0.255. 
   If any of those conditions are met the browser will not use the proxy for that destination but will be told to go directly. External domains will always have full stops e.g. ".com" etc. Likewise .local is usually used for internal networks. And 192.168.0.0/127.0.0.0 are fairly standard **private** IP ranges. All those rules simply **attempt** avoid using the proxy for **calls** to internal sites/applications. Without knowing your network setup or the reason for using a proxy in the first place I can't really offer much in a way of recommendations with the configuration. If you're looking to simply manage internet surfing then it should do the trick.

Comment: By everyone I take it you mean all clients? I think the only one that will give you problems is firefox as it uses it's own settings to select a proxy. IE and Chrome use the "Internet Options" settings found in your controls panels. So firefox won't pick up the changes from dhcp or dns deployment from either PAC or WPAD files. That said you can use Group Policy to set the Auto Configuration option but there is still some manual work involved. If you mean all destinations (local + external)  `function FindProxyForURL(url,host) {return "PROXY 192.168.0.1:3128";}` should be enough

Comment: You have answered the first question correctly. I do not need the 3 files. Regarding the answer to the second question, unfortunately the two configurations that you have proposed have not worked (only mine works correctly). Please review the proposed settings again, to verify if there is an error and to be able to select your answer as correct.

Comment: When you say worked correctly do you mean the configs I provided aren't functioning as expected or at all? Can't really see what's wrong with either but if your works I'd go with it. I've checked both syntaxes with [link](https://proxyforurl.thorsen.pm/) and my first answer produces all the same output as yours. The second config just says no matter what just use proxy which probably isn't recommended because it can get in the way if you're running applications locally. e.g. request to test webserver on localhost (127.0.0.1) would also get passed to proxy where localhost refers to proxy itself

Comment: Let's do one thing Please answer me if you consider that my configuration is correct and if you think there is a bad line, tell me and that is enough

Comment: It's pretty standard config so there's nothing really wrong with it. But I'll briefly explain what each condition does and you can decide if that's what you want.

Comment: My internal range is only 192.168.1.0/24 and proxy (localhost 127.0.0.1) is 192.168.1.10:3128. What's left?

Comment: Feel free to change the 192 rule to `isInNet(dnsResolve(host), "192.168.1.0",  "255.255.255.0")`. I'm not sure you're understanding localhost correctly. Localhost which as a rule of thumb resolves to 127.0.0.1 is what most devices refer to themselves with. Let's say I'm running apache serving a static webpage on my pc on port 8080. If i browse for localhost:8080 the browser will look on my pc. If however 127.0.0.1 goes to proxy, then from the proxy servers viewpoint it will think 127.0.0.1 refers to itself and will look at what is running on port 8080 either serving nothing or wrong content.